# error on paypal\rest-api-sdk-php\lib\PayPal\Transport\PayPalRestCall.php

Tags: sdk, paypal-sandbox

this is the code where i have problem
i had the api paypal downloasded whi composer.json
i get the error

"Notice: Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_SSLVERSION - assumed 'CURLOPT_SSLVERSION' in C:\wamp\www\Nouveau dossier\vendor\paypal\rest-api-sdk-php\lib\PayPal\Transport\PayPalRestCall.php on line 57"

```
<?php

use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\Details;
use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;

require '../src/start.php';

$payer = new Payer();
$details = new Details();
$amount= new Amount();
$transaction = new Transaction();
$payment = new Payment();
$redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();



$payer->setPaymentMethod("paypal");

//detail
$details->setShipping('2.00')
->setTax('0.00')
->setSubtotal('20.00');

// amount
$amount->setCurrency('GBP')
        ->setTotal('22.00')
        ->setDetails($details);

// transaction
$transaction->setAmount($amount)
            ->setDescription('membership');

// payment
$payment->setIntent('sale')
    ->setPayer($payer)
    ->setTransactions([$transaction]);
//redirectUrls

$redirectUrls->setReturnUrl('http://localhost/Nouveau%20dossier/paypal/pay.php?approved=true')
            ->setCancelUrl('http://localhost/Nouveau%20dossier/paypal/pay.php?approved=false');

$payment->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);
try{
    $payment->create($api);


}
 catch (PayPal\Exception\PPConnectionException $ex) {
    echo "Exception: " . $ex->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($ex->getData());   
    exit(1);

//catch(PPConnectionException $e){
//header('Location: ../paypal/error.php');
}
//foreach($payment->getLinks() as $link){
//if($link->getRek() == 'approval_url'){

    //$redirectUrl = $link->getHref();

//}
//}
//var_dump($redirectUrl);
$approvalUrl = $payment->getApprovalLink();
?>
```

Comment: Can you confirm if you have PHP higher than 5.1.0, and your curl is latest ?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using PHP 5.1+, this error means that you do not have `PHP cUrl` installed (or, your php.ini is not configured to use cUrl). I was facing the same problem on my Ubuntu host and after installing cUrl and restarting the server, problem got solved. To install cUrl, type the following in your SSH console:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

Then restart your apache server:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Of course, commands will be different for different type of servers.

Comment: glad i could help @VinothKumar :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on DigitalOcean.com hosting. I just restarted the droplet and the problem went away.